# How do I run a specific vim command when opening a file with a given extension?

Tags: vimrc, filetype

I want all of my files ending in `.tex` to have line length 80. So whenever I open a `.tex` file in vim I type `:set tw=79`. What would I put in my .vimrc to automate this?

What if I wanted it to work with a specific list of filetypes, say, `.md`, `.txt`, and `.tex`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of checking the extension and setting the textwidth accordingly you could simply create a `tex.vim` (the name must match the filetype) file in `.vim/ftplugin/` or for Windows `$HOME/vimfiles/ftplugin/` and set textwidth there. This will help you to keep your .vimrc clean.

Your `.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim` file would look like:

```
setlocal textwidth=79
```

As 8bittree said in the comments you also have to enable `filetype plugins` in your vimrc (I woudln't know why anybody would not enable it):

```
filetype plugin on
```

Read this for more information: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_your_vimrc_file_clean

Comment: You'll also want to make sure filetype plugins are enabled in your `.vimrc` with `filetype plugin on`.

Answer (score 12):

In `~/.vimrc` you can add the following line:

```
au BufReadPost,BufNewFile *.md,*.txt,*.tex setlocal tw=79
```

<sup>For extra commands, separate them by `|`.</sup>

This will set your settings right after reading the file, or opening a new file into the buffer for specific extensions.

Comment: `set` can take any number of settings. Something like `set tw=79 nowrap formatoptions+=j` will work. No need for a `|` (unless you want to call a different command, of course) ;-)